# How can I generate a CREATE TABLE statement from a SELECT statement in Datagrip?

Tags: mysql, create-table, datagrip

Is there a way to generate a `CREATE TABLE` statement from a `SELECT` statement (that is built from many `JOIN`s)?

I can only find it for tables and views. But my problem is that I am using Google Cloud SQL (mysql version) and I cannot change the settings to use the `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT * ...`.

Is there a way to do it handy in `DataGrip`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

1. You need to execute the query and get results
2. Then in result set select *"Export data..."* and select *"SQL Inserts"*
3. Check *"Add table definition(DDL)"*

[image: create table]

Detailed feature request and description are mentioned in the issue [DBE-8596](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8596)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be actually creating a new table from the result you have. Use **Copy to database** button.

[image]

Comment: I somehow can't get this activated, it's disabled.

Comment: I am from DataGrip team. It is very unusual. Can you please send a screenshot or file it here? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE